# Get Content and Href of Elements that Have A Certain Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a Div with 9 Spans as its member. 3 of them has "aaa" Class, 3 of them has "bbb" Class, and 3 of them has "ccc" Class. The format is:

```
    <span class="aaa">aaa</span>
    <span class="bbb"><strong>bbb</strong></span>
    <span class="ccc"><a href="0.html">ccc</a></span>

    <span class="aaa">aaa1</span>
    <span class="bbb"><strong>bbb1</strong></span>
    <span class="ccc"><a href="1.html">ccc1</a></span>

    <span class="aaa">aaa2</span>
    <span class="bbb"><strong>bbb2</strong></span>
    <span class="ccc"><a href="2.html">ccc2</a></span>
```

There is also an Unordered List.

What I want is to populate the Unordered List with List Items. The new format of the Unordered List should be like this:

```
<ul class="container">
    <li>
        <a href="0.html">
            aaabbb
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="1.html">
            aaa1bbb1
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="2.html">
            aaa2bbb2
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My code is below, but it doesn't work:

http://jsfiddle.net/Tgser/

How can I format the Unordered List like above?

Comment: Code in red in jsFiddle tells you that something is wrong...Plus, you have html, js and css sections and you don't need to add doctype etc. Also, you're not including the jQuery library under "Framework"

Comment: Yes, i know. Maybe because I mixed HTML with Javacript in HTML section. If you copy it into Notepad++, it will be fine...

Comment: I included the jQuery library. Please copy the whole code to your web development IDE...

Comment: Isn't it just easier for everybody if you just take 5 sec to properly present the code? --> http://jsfiddle.net/Tgser/4/

Comment: Thanks... Actually I was doing it...

Comment: **Jasper** solution should work

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. It works perfectly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function()
{
    //you can use `.filter()` to filter a list down to the elements you want, hasClass() returns true/false, not a set of elements
    var allLatestNews = $('.source').children(),
        span_aaa = allLatestNews.filter('.aaa'),
        span_bbb = allLatestNews.filter('.bbb'),
        span_ccc = allLatestNews.filter('.ccc'),
        output   = [];//this is used to add HTML to the DOM

    //you only need to loop the number of elements in each `span_***` variable, not the total number of span elements
    for(var i = 0; i < span_aaa.length; i++)
    {
        //instead of manipulating the DOM every iteration of the loop, we add the string of HTML to an array
        output.push('<li><a href="' + span_ccc.eq(i).children().attr("href") + '">' + span_aaa.eq(i).text()+ span_bbb.eq(i).text() + span_ccc.eq(i).text() + '</a></li>');
    }

    //then we append all the HTML at once
    $('.container').append(output.join(''));
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Tgser/5/

Notice the use of `.text()` to get the text of the `<span>` elements and the use of `.eq(i)` to select the jQuery object for the corresponding index (`i`) rather than using `[i]` which selects the corresponding `DOMElement`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's very complicated

Comment: Thanks for your further explanation. I never knew the difference between .eq(i) and [i] before.